# Set Image size in Image block but the page is showing the image with different height and width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm creating a new site in wordpress with WooCommerce I'm using the Astra theme. I want to create a page with two images side by side and with the same height.
I have added two columns and one image block in each column and I have resized the two images and they looks ok in gutenberg:

[image]

[image]

But when I visualize the page the two images have different size than what was set in gutenberg:

[image]

Do you know how I can obtain the right height?

Answer (score -1):

use this code to get the same size image

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"><img src="1.jpg"><div>
   <div class="col-md-6"><img src="2.jpg"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to change the theme code. I want just to understand why the image size setting of gutemberg are not working.

Comment: You need to add this code, image actual px will not display in web page in wordpress.